# Implementing resizing an image in c#

Tags: c#, image-processing

I have implemented a function to resize images vertically in c# (zooming). It takes two parameters: the image to be resized and new height of the image. Here is my code:

```
  public static Bitmap ScaleUpDown(Bitmap b, int height)
    {
        Bitmap scaledImage = new Bitmap(b.Width, height);

        int scaleRatio = height / b.Height;

        if (scaleRatio >= 1)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < b.Width; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < b.Height; j++)
                {
                    Color pixel = b.GetPixel(i, j);

                    int fill = 0;
                    while (fill < scaleRatio)
                    {
                        scaledImage.SetPixel(i, scaleRatio * j + fill, pixel);
                        fill++;
                    }

                }
            }
        }

        return scaledImage;
    }
```

Here is what i do: i visit every pixel, copy it and paste it to the next row in the same column or columns based on the proportion of resizing. My problem is, this code works fine only if the new height is the multiple of the old height, such as 2*oldHeight, 3*oldHeight etc. What if new height should be 1.5 times or 1.3 times bigger than the old height? What can i do about that?

Thanks

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. `BroTip:` use a `Viewbox`. Don't waste your time trying to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: I assume this is an excersize? You do know that .Net offers resizing/scaling out-of-the-box (and that there are tons of libraries doing the heavy lifting for you if you need more than basic resizing/scaling)?

Comment: @RobIII yes, i know .Net offers it but i am trying to implement it. Is it a too hard thing to do? I am new to image processing and trying to understand how that works so i want to implement it myself

Comment: @HighCore what did you not understand about what i am asking? I can try to explain

Comment: As long as this is for educational purposes or fun or whatever: go ahead. Enjoy! Just keep in mind that the wheel has been invented before and lots of other (most likely better) options exist. Also: there are many methods (algorithms) like bilinear, bicubic, nearest neighbour etc. that each have their strengths / benefits / results.

Comment: Use the Bitmap(Image, int, int) constructor instead.

Comment: You have to tell us what you want it to do.  For example, if the original image is 3 pixels tall, and you want to rescale to 4 pixels tall, what should it do?  Repeat one of the rows?  Make each row the average of its neighbors?

Comment: Take a look at the image processing theory before asking here. SO is to ask specific *programming* questions. Take a look here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_scaling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_scaling for detailed explanations on image scaling and related algorithms.